# Generating 10 random numbers

Tags: php

I am trying to display 10 random numbers from an array of numbers with no success.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$num = array("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009");

//echo $num[rand(0,9)];
echo '<br/>';
for ($num = 2000; $num <= 10; $num[rand(0,9)]++)
{
    echo "The number is " . $num . "<br />";
}
?>
```

The script doesn't display anything although I have `display_errors = On` on my ubuntu php.ini.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function instead.

```
<?php
$num = array("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009");
shuffle($num);
echo '<br/>';
foreach ($num as $value)
  {
  echo "The number is " . $value . "<br />";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Note, that `shuffle` changes the source array

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`array_rand`](http://php.net/array_rand):

```
array_rand($num, 10); // returns a new array with 10 randomly selected values.
```

After that you can iterate over these with `foreach`:

```
$rand = array_rand($num, 10);

foreach($rand as $key) {
  echo "The number is " . $num[key] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Also he should use `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

Try [shuffle()](http://www.php.net/manual/function.shuffle.php)

```
$num= array("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", 
  "2009");

shuffle($num);

 //echo $num[rand(0,9)];
 echo '<br/>';
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($num); $i++)
 {
  echo "The number is " . $num[$i] . "<br />";
 }
```

Comment: provide your links in english :)

Answer (score 0):

You starts your loop from `$num = 2000` and stops when `$num <= 10`. So it doesnt execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $num= array("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", 
  "2009");

 //echo $num[rand(0,9)];
 echo '<br/>';
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($num); $i++)
 {
  echo "The number is " . $num[rand(0, count($num))] . "<br />";
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $num= array("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009");

    for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
        $rand = rand(0,count($num));
        echo "The number is " . $num[$rand] . "<br />";

        // unset($num[$rand]); //to get unique numbers each time .. this will unset array item after its showed
        // $num = array_values($num); //reindex after unset
    }
```

unset and array_values you can use if you want to get only unique results

Comment: `for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)` - it will execute 11 times